# Почему не запускается код в PyCharm?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pycharm

При запуске кода выводятся две ошибки. Их я отметил в коде как "#<<<---------ERROR"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Захар\Desktop\Часы\watch_s.py", line 309, in

w = ManinWindow()

File "C:\Users\Захар\Desktop\Часы\watch_s.py", line 101, in **init**

self.setupUi(self)

File "C:\Users\Захар\Desktop\Часы\watch_s.py", line 70, in setupUi

self.layout_t = QGridLayout(self.tab_3)

AttributeError: 'ManinWindow' object has no attribute 'tab_3'. Did you mean: 'tab_2'?

Вот код:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(649, 168)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(999999, 999999))
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet(
        "MainWindow\n""{\n""    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);\n""}")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(99999, 999999))
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37)\n""")
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -1, 641, 171))
    self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(99999, 999))
    self.frame.setStyleSheet(
        "MainWindow\n""{\n""    background-color:rgb(46, 46, 46)\n""}")
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.frame)
    self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 651, 161))
    self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(4, 0))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Rio Glamour personal use")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(
        "QTabWidget::pane\n"
        "{\n""    border: 1px;\n"
        "    background: rgb(37, 37, 37);\n"
        "}\n""\n"
        "QTabBar::tab\n""{\n""    background: rgb(37, 37, 37);\n"
        "    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""}\n""\n""\n"
        "QTabBar::tab:selected\n""{\n"
        "    background:rgb(26, 26, 26);\n"
        "    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""}\n""\n"
        "QTabBar::tab:hover\n""{\n""    background:rgb(57, 57, 57);\n"
        "    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""}\n""\n""")
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
    self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(8)
    self.tab.setFont(font)
    self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -8, 651, 141))
    self.label.setText("")
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")

    self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")

    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 661, 141))
    self.label_2.setText("")
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

    self.layout = QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 5)

    self.layout_timer = QGridLayout(self.tab_3)                        #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--ERROR
    self.layout_timer.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 2)

    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
    self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_3.setStyleSheet(
        "background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);\n""color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 661, 141))
    self.label_3.setText("")
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow) 

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Time"))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Timer"))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Stopwatch"))

class ManinWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)   #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<---ERROR

    self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.current_index)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    self.working_clock = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.working_clock.setInterval(1000)
    self.working_clock.timeout.connect(self.display_clock)
    self.working_clock.start()

def add_functions(self): #main functions
    # Часы --- tab_2
    self.label.setText(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('HH:mm:ss\ndd MM yyyy'))
    self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Capsuula", 40))
    self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #DADDFC;")
    self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

    # Таймер --- tab_2

    self.label_2.setText("00:00:00")
    self.label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.label_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Capsuula", 45))
    self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #fff;")

    self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
    self.btn_start.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.func_start_timer)

    self.btn_continue = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Continue")
    self.btn_continue.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_continue.clicked.connect(self.func_continue_timer)

    self.btn_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Reset")
    self.btn_reset.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_reset.clicked.connect(self.func_reset_timer)

    self.startDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
    today = QDate.currentDate()
    DATETIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    self.startDateTime.setDateRange(today, today)
    self.startDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
    self.startDateTime.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccc; font-size: 12px;')

    self.endDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
    self.endDateTime.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
    self.endDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
    self.endDateTime.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccc; font-size: 12px;')

    startLabel = QLabel('Start', styleSheet='color: #fff; font-size: 12px;')
    startLabel.setFixedSize(30, 25)
    self.layout.addWidget(startLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.startDateTime, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    endLabel = QLabel("End:", styleSheet='color: #fff; font-size: 12px;')
    endLabel.setFixedSize(30, 25)
    self.layout.addWidget(endLabel, 1, 2, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.endDateTime, 1, 3, 1, 1)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_start, 1, 4, 1, 1)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_continue, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_reset, 2, 3, 1, 1)

    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.setInterval(1000)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_time_timer)

    #Секундомер --- tab_3

    self.temp = 0
    self.label_2.setText("00:00:00")
    self.label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.label_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Capsuula", 40))
    self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #f00;")

    self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
    self.btn_start.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.func_start)

    self.btn_continue = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Continue")
    self.btn_continue.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_continue.clicked.connect(self.func_continue)

    self.btn_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Reset")
    self.btn_reset.setStyleSheet("color: #fff; font-size: 15px; background-color: #555;")
    self.btn_reset.clicked.connect(self.func_reset)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_start, 1, 0, 1, 2)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_continue, 2, 0, 1, 1)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_reset, 2, 1, 1, 1)

    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.setInterval(1000)

    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_time)

#STOPWATCH FUNCTIONS ---VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

def func_start(self):
    if self.btn_start.text() == "Start":
        self.timer.start()
        self.btn_start.setText("Stop")
    else:
        self.timer.stop()
        self.btn_start.setText("Start")
        self.btn_start.hide()
        self.btn_continue.show()
        self.btn_reset.show()

def func_reset(self):
    self.temp = 0
    self.label_2.setText("00:00:00")
    self.btn_start.setText("Start")
    self.btn_start.show()
    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()

def display_time(self):
    f_temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(self.temp).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    self.label_2.setText(f_temp)
    self.temp += 1


def current_index(self, index):
    if index == 0:
        self.add_functions()

def func_continue(self):
    self.timer.start()
    self.btn_start.setText('Стоп')
    self.btn_start.show()
    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()


    #TIMER FUNCTIONS ---VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

def func_start_timer(self):
    if self.btn_start.text() == "Start":
        self.timer.start()
        self.btn_start.setText("Stop")

        start_date = self.startDateTime.dateTime()
        self.start_date_py = start_date.toPyDateTime()
        end_date = self.endDateTime.dateTime()
        self.end_date_py = end_date.toPyDateTime()

        self.d = self.end_date_py - self.start_date_py  # !!!
    else:
        self.timer.stop()
        self.btn_start.setText("Start")
        self.btn_start.hide()
        self.btn_continue.show()
        self.btn_reset.show()

def func_reset_timer(self):
    self.label_2.setText("00:00:00")
    self.btn_start.setText("Start")
    self.btn_start.show()
    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()

def display_time_timer(self):
    mm, ss = divmod(self.d.seconds, 60)  # !!!
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)  # !!!

    self.label_2.setText(
        f'{self.d.days} d. {hh:02} h. {mm:02} min. {ss:02} sec.'
    )

    self.d = self.d - timedelta(seconds=1)  # !!!

    if self.d.days < 0:  # !!!
        self.timer.stop()

def current_index_timer(self, index):
    if index == 0:
        self.add_functions()

def func_continue_timer(self):
    if self.d.days < 0:
        return

    self.timer.start()
    self.btn_start.setText('Стоп')
    self.btn_start.show()
    self.btn_continue.hide()
    self.btn_reset.hide()



def display_clock(self):              #clock functions
    self.label.setText(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('HH:mm:ss\ndd MM yyyy'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ManinWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Уточняю ошибку на линии 70. Мне нужна именно "tab_3", но не "tab_2"

Comment: ZXXR sorry, а что с вашим предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: Он мне помог, я просто сделал перестановку функций по вкладкам

Comment: @S.Nick Кстати, у вас есть какая-либо соцсеть для связи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты сначала исспользуешь переменную, а затем инициализируешь

```
    self.layout_timer = QGridLayout(self.tab_3) #use но таб3 ещё не существует                        #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--ERROR
    self.layout_timer.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 2)

    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
    self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget() #init
```

то есть это что то вроде

```
...
result=x-1
x=10
...
```

то есть перенеси инициализацию tab_3 в начало функции, по крайней мере до первого использования

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исправлена